# Preload Jquery Animation

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm looking for the best way to preload images with jQuery.
I tried using different library but don't work.
I want to make http://farzaddaliri.com/ like a Google site

Answer (score 0):

you can add blur lightweight background image to div or images so user first see blur background then the real image

```
img{
   background: url('blur.jpg');
}
```